# Oracle sql statement on very large table

Tags: sql, oracle

I relative new to sql and I have a statement which takes forever to run.

```
SELECT
  sum(a.amountcur)
FROM
  custtrans a
WHERE
  a.transdate <= '2013-12-31';
```

I's a large table but the statemnt takes about 6 minutes!
Any ideas why?

Comment: Post explain plan of the same. It gives more lights

Comment: 1. Define forever. Is it seconds, minutes, hours?  2. Do not relay on implicit data type conversion, ever. In your situation use `to_date()` function to convert your character literal that represents a date to a value of `data` data type. so your predicate might look like this: `where a.transdate <= to_date('2013-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` or `where a.transdate <= date '2013-12-31'`. Plus it's always a good idea to provide a bit more information about how big your table is, what is the execution plan, is there any indexes in place and so forth.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov You read my mind :)

Answer (score 2):

Your select, as you post it, will read 99% of the whole table (2013-12-31 is just a week ago, and i assume most entries are before that date and only very few after). If your table has many large columns (like varchar2(4000)), all that data will be read as well when oracle scans the table. So you might read several KB each row just to get the 30 bytes you need for amountcur and transdate.

If you have this scenario. create a combined index on transdate and amountcur:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON custtrans(transdate, amountcur)
```

With the combined index, oracle can read the index to fulfill your query and doesn't have to touch the main table at all, which might result in considerably less data that needs to be read from disk.

Comment: LOBS are stored outside the actual table by default. So unless you select any LOB column they are not read from disc.

Comment: plus 1 - this is the most efficient and fastest index.  The underlying  table does not need to touched.  The only possible faster way to do it would be to partition the index.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the table has an index on transdate.

```
  create index custtrans_idx on custtrans (transdate);
```

Also if this field is defined as a date in the table then do

```
 SELECT sum(a.amountcur)
   FROM custtrans a
   WHERE a.transdate <= to_date('2013-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: When he selects "everything until a week ago", this index might hurt more than it helps, because the query will still read 99% of the data table AND the index on top.

Comment: That is an incorrect statement.   Oracle will read the b-tree index (log n ^ n speed) obtain only the pertinent rowids and then access the table.

Comment: Having said that, your post with having the index span both columns is better because oracle can do an index only scan.

Comment: From the date he's selecting (2013-12-31) and today, which is only one week later, i assume the index will return all but very few rows, so after reading the index, he will read most of the table anyway.

Comment: The index contains the date and the rowid.  Once oracle has the rowid, accessing the table is one hop.  Granted the table needs to be in the sga--if this is your point than I understand.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is really large, the query has to scan every row with `transdate` below given.

Even if you have an index on `transdate` and it helps to stop the scan early (which it may not), when the number of matching rows is very high, it would take considerable time to scan them all and sum the values.

To speed things up, you could calculate partial sums, e.g. for each passed month, assuming that your data is historical and past does not change. Then you'd only need to scan `custtrans` only for 1-2 months, then quickly scan the table with monthly sums, and add the results.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create an index on the column used in the where clause (this is useful if you want to retrieve only 10-15% rows by using indexed column).

Another option is to partition your table if it has millions of rows. In this case also if you try to retrieve 70-80% data, it wont help.

The best option is first to analyze your requirements and then make a choice.

Whenever you deal with date functions it's better to use `to_date()` function. Do not rely on implicit data type conversion.

Comment: What is a "ur table" or a "u deal"?

Comment: If you select let's say 90% of all table data, then partitioning does not change anything in terms of performance.

Comment: -1.. First thing should never be to just create an index.  First thing is to get WAY more information.  You should understand where the time is going, the amount of data needed to be scanned to get the result, and how that data is located in the table (indexes are helpful for eliminating block visits.. percent of rows is comparatively irrelevant)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an index only on column amountcur:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON custtrans(amountcur)
```

In this case Oracle will read most probably only the Index (Index Full Scan), nothing else.

Correction, as mentioned in comment. It must be a composite Index:

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON custtrans(transdate, amountcur)
```

But maybe it is a bit useless to create an index just for a single select statement.

Comment: Oracle would still have to read the query to satisfy the WHERE clause, as transdate is not in your index.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In this case it must be a composite index. I will change my post